# Mongoose CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "XXX" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Employee"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, mern

Im building a MERN application and I want to have a list of employees containing the name when i visit the endpoint /employees/:name
Eg: /employees/robert should return a list of all the employees containing the name robert.

server.js

```js
app.get("/api/employees/:name", async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  const employees = await EmployeeModel.find({ name: { "$regex": name, "$options": "i" } }).exec();
  return res.json(employees);
})
```

EmployeeModel.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  level: String,
  position: String,
  equipment: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", EmployeeSchema);
```

```
path\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4884
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "robert" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Employee"
    at model.Query.exec (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4884:21)
    at Query.then (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4983:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"robert"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'robert',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (\server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (\server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
      at castObjectId (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1201:12)
      at SchemaType._castForQuery (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1648:15)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1636:15)
      at SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1612:20)   
      at cast (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:347:32)
      at Query.cast (\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5312:12),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

The routes:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <EmployeeList />,
      },
      {
        path: "/employees/:name",
        element: <EmployeeNameSearch />,
      },
      {
        path: "/equipments",
        element: <EquipmentList />
      },
      {
        path: "/create",
        element: <EmployeeCreator />,
      },
      {
        path: "/update",
        element: <Update />
      },
      {
        path: "/update/:id",
        element: <EmployeeUpdater />,
      },
      {
        path: "/update/equipment/:id",
        element: <EquipmentUpdater />
      },
      {
        path: "/missing",
        element: <Missing />
      },
      {
        path: "/table-test",
        element: <TableTest />,
      },
      {
        path: "/form-test",
        element: <FormTest />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

maybe my logic is wrong but i dont think the whole server should crash because of it.

Comment: Please post all your routes. It might be you have another route that picks up your request before it get to the one you think.

Comment: yes, thats the problem

Comment: I should have been clearer. Please post your route handlers i.e (`app.get()` , `app.post()`) in exactly the same order you have them in your code. From your server.js I imagine.

Comment: Yes i realized after i posted it. You were right i had 2 /employees/:id and /employees/:name. I fixed it now. Thanks